# Calculate depart flights from sorted data using Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, mapreduce, window-functions

I've a dataset of flights in the form of

`+----------------+----------+-------------+
|flightID        |depart_ts |arrival_ts   |
+----------------+----------+-------------+
|1               |1451603468|   1451603468|
|2               |1451603468|   1451603468|
|3               |1451603468|   1451603468|
|4               |1451603468|   1451603468|
|5               |1451603468|   1451603468|
+----------------+----------+-------------+`

and my job is to use Apache Spark to find the return flight for each flight given some conditions (departure time of return flight B should be within 2 hours from arrival time of flight A). Doing a cross join of 1M Record to check these conditions is not efficient and will cost much time. I've thought about using window function with 1 partition and custom UDAF to do the calculation. Something like this

```
1. val flightsWindow = Window.orderBy("depart_ts").rangeBetween(0, 7200)


2. flights.withColumn("returnFlightID", calcReturn( $"arrival_ts", $"depart_ts").over(flightsWindow)).show()
```

Considering that this approach will lead to a solution, I'm facing some challenges:

1. In line 1, I want to let frame range span from CURRENT ROW to arrival_ts + 7200, but apparently I cannot do dynamic ranges in spark, no?
2. In line 1 and assuming that 2 flights have the same arrival time, this will make it impossible to retrieve the values of the second flight when CURRENT_ROW pointer moves there, since difference between first flight and second flight is 0. Is it possible to explicitly tell range to start framing from CURRENT_ROW?
3. In line 2, I want to retrieve the depart_ts value for the very first row of the frame to compare against other flights in the frame. Is it possible to do that. I tried first() function but it doesn't fit in my case.

Comment: If you're going to use single node why bother with Spark? Just loop over the data.... And if you're interested in frame `arrival_ts + 7200` just `orderBy("arrival_ts")`.

Comment: I know how simple to do that in a single node but I'm challenging myself to come up with a solution in a dist environment for the sake of learning. I though about orderingBy arrival_ts but I will have the same problem since I want to fullfill this condition
`flightA.arrivalTime + 2 hours > flightB.departTime` 
and in both cases I will have to compare 2 columns and consider only the frame with flightB depart time within 2 hours of flightA arrival time